# CakePHP CamelCase names after upload on server

Tags: cakephp, upload, camelcasing

My problem is quite strange. I'm developing CakePHP application. At the beginning I was doing all stuff on my local server with Windows... and works pretty good. But now I had to do upload to company's server. Now the app doesn't work due to CamelCase convention. My filenames looks like this: `PostCategoriesController`. On local Windows server there's no problem. But after upload when I type web address in my browser I see `PostcategoriesController could not be found`. I know Windows and Linux are case-sensitive in different ways. However in Cookbook we can read that developers should use CamelCase convention, so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You've probably made a mistake somewhere like using `postcategories` instead of `post_categories` in the URL or in a route...

Comment: yea, in URLs I'm using postcategories without underscore, but on local server it works...
Anyway, thanks for help :)

Comment: Ok, let me add that as an actual answer so that this question appears resolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As figured in the comments, you were using `postcategories` instead of something like `post_categories` in the URL, and so CakePHP cannot properly inflect this to `PostCategories` as there is no separator for the the words, and so you'll end up with `Postcategories`, which only works only Windows systems as its filesystems are case-insensitive (except for NFS on some server version if I remember correctly).

See also **[Cookbook > CakePHP conventions > URL Considerations for Controller Names](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#url-considerations-for-controller-names)**

As can be seen in the docs it's also possible to use uppercase chars to indicate multiple words, ie `postCastegories` or `PostCategories` would work in a URL too.